# A formular for finding how many prime numbers there are below a number

Tags: calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers

With $f(n)=8n+8(n-1)+8(n-2)+\cdots+(8\cdot1)+1$, it is possible to calculate how many primes there are below $f(n)$ using $P(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+3n$.

**Example:**
When $n=3$,  $f(3)=49$ and $P(3)=15$.

That means below 49 there are 15 primes.

It is also possible to know how many primes are between $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_0)$ using $p(x_1)-p(x_0)$

**Is this a known formula? I tested this with a bunch of numbers I counted manually using Ulam Spiral. I would like to know whether my thinking is right.**

**How did I came to this conclusion:**

I noticed that in Ulam Spiral every time the spiral goes around it contains exactly 8 more numbers than the last one and exactly one more prime number than the last round.

**Example:**

- first round (2-9) has 8 numbers and 4 primes
- second round (10-25) has 16 numbers and 5 primes
- third round (26-49) has 24 numbers and 6 primes

and so on.

Comment: I don't even understand your definition of $f(n)$. And no there is no such polynomial formula for $\pi(f(n))$ for any sequence $f(n)$ with a good and simple enough asymptotic.

Comment: Which, by the way is $4(n^2+n)-7$. Run this through mathematica and you'll see it doesn't fit.

Comment: @Rohan Yes I will edit that. Thank you!!

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE are you referring to f(n) or p(n)?

Comment: $f(n)$ is what I referred to.

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot guys I can sleep peacefully tonight. xD
Much love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula first fails at $n=7$, where it predicts $49$ primes below $225$ but in fact there are only $48$.

The error increases as $n$ increases, for example for $n=100$ the formula predicts $5350$ primes below $40401$ but there are actually only $4236$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is not correct.  Your claim is that up to $(2n+1)^2$ there are $\frac 12n(n+7)=\frac 12n^2+\frac 72n$ primes.  In fact for $n=8$ your formula predicts $60$ primes and there are $61$.  It predicts that the density of primes approaches $\frac 18$, while we know it approaches $0$ about as $\frac 1{\log n}$

Answer (score 0):

One can also show this fails by using $\pi(n)\sim\frac{x}{ln(x)}$, the Prime Number Theorem. With your $P(n)$, this limit fails at infinity.